# R- Machine Learning for Multiple Linear Regression WITHOUT categorical variables

Tags: r, regression

Hello I want to develop a multiple linear regression equation for my dataset. I have 2 independent continous variables and 24 data points (with dependent variable outcome). I have actually made a regression equation using the `lm( y~ x1 + x2, data=df)`function but I want to use machine learning and split my data into train and test sets. Then I want to predict PM concentration using the best model I gained. When I look at websites I always find examples containing categorical variables but I do not see any examples using continous variables.

How can I find a great example and what path should I follow?

Thank you

Edit: This was one of the things I have tried.

```
> library(caret)
> dim(df)
[1] 24  3
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     PM   SO2 Wind_speed
  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 108.   7.57        0.9
2 115.   9.45        0.9
3  74.5 13.4         1.2
4  77.2  7.73        1.3
5  57.0  5.08        1.3
6  52.6  8.59        1.2
> summary(df)
       PM              SO2           Wind_speed   
 Min.   : 52.64   Min.   : 4.090   Min.   :0.600  
 1st Qu.: 76.84   1st Qu.: 7.397   1st Qu.:0.800  
 Median :105.69   Median : 9.265   Median :1.000  
 Mean   :118.62   Mean   :17.089   Mean   :1.004  
 3rd Qu.:158.02   3rd Qu.:15.070   3rd Qu.:1.200  
 Max.   :261.84   Max.   :75.270   Max.   :1.500  
> control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
> summary(control)
                  Length Class 
method            1      -none-
number            1      -none-
repeats           1      -none-
search            1      -none-
p                 1      -none-
initialWindow     0      -none-
horizon           1      -none-
fixedWindow       1      -none-
skip              1      -none-
verboseIter       1      -none-
returnData        1      -none-
returnResamp      1      -none-
savePredictions   1      -none-
classProbs        1      -none-
summaryFunction   1      -none-
selectionFunction 1      -none-
preProcOptions    6      -none-
sampling          0      -none-
index             0      -none-
indexOut          0      -none-
indexFinal        0      -none-
timingSamps       1      -none-
predictionBounds  2      -none-
seeds             1      -none-
adaptive          4      -none-
trim              1      -none-
allowParallel     1      -none-
                  Mode     
method            character
number            numeric  
repeats           logical  
search            character
p                 numeric  
initialWindow     NULL     
horizon           numeric  
fixedWindow       logical  
skip              numeric  
verboseIter       logical  
returnData        logical  
returnResamp      character
savePredictions   logical  
classProbs        logical  
summaryFunction   function 
selectionFunction character
preProcOptions    list     
sampling          NULL     
index             NULL     
indexOut          NULL     
indexFinal        NULL     
timingSamps       numeric  
predictionBounds  logical  
seeds             logical  
adaptive          list     
trim              logical  
allowParallel     logical  
> metric <- "Accuracy"
> set.seed(7)
> fit.lda <- train(PM~., data=df, method="lda", metric=metric, trControl=control)
Hata: wrong model type for regression
>set.seed(7)
> fit.cart <- train(PM~., data= df, method="rpart", metric=metric, trControl=control)
Hata: Metric Accuracy not applicable for regression models
```

Comment: Simply continue your desk research. There are tons of examples with continuous variables for linear regression. Besides, there's nothing special in using continuous over ctageroial variables and similar machine learning rules would apply.

Comment: One note of caution: if you only have 24 data points, your data size is very likely to be too low even for the "normal" approach where you just create your linear regression equation. It doesn't make sense to split these 24 data points up into two even smaller subsets and use a train/test scenario.

Comment: @deschen Actually I do think similarly. My teacher recommended this. However, as you said I have a very small dataset which will very likely give out an inaccurate answer. Another point is I have tried trying a model. The code goes like this: `fit.cart <- train(PM~., data= df, method="rpart", metric=metric, trControl=control)
Error: Metric Accuracy not applicable for regression models` What does this imply? Thanks

Comment: The message is relatively clear. You are setting a parameter `metric = metric` (not sure though, how you defined the metric object in the first place) and probably selected one that is not appropriate for regression models (as opposed to categorial metrics).

Comment: Also, please share your full code, otherwise it's impossible to determine what's going on. Also, check the help for the train funtion (assuming you are using the package rpart). The help is pretty clear in terms of which parameters are allowed in `metric` for regression models.

Comment: @deschen hello I added my code on post. Thanks

Comment: Please read my last comment. It is very clear in the help function taht "accuracy" is not allowed as a "metric" for regression models.

Comment: I think you also got that I do not get the idea so tried to fit the code on the internet on my data. :') I think that is why I cannot actually perform anything. I learned how you can split your data into train and test set and I used : `set.seed(123)
sample=sample.split(df, SplitRatio=0.70)
train1 = subset(df, sample ==TRUE)
test1=subset(df, sample==FALSE)`  but as you might guess that also did not work. It gave this error:  `Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector. i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input. x Input has size 24 but subscript r has size 3. `

Comment: Sorry I did not catch that. Then should I erase "Accuracy" by writing `rm("Accuracy")`. Do I need to input anything for `metric`function? Thank you

Comment: type `?caret::train` and scroll to the place where the `metric` is described. Change "Accuracy" to one of the options mentioend for regression models. However, this is just fire fighting. You won't get a proper regression model with 24 data points, regardless of fixing the metric issue.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your help. I think it is the best if I just go with my equation derived from `lm` function. Otherwise it is too complicated for only 24 data points.